# How would I generate a unique ID to a set of rows based on a timestamp column?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following table:

| Prospect_ID | Channel | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23455 | Digital | 01/01/2020 10:00:00 |
| 23455 | Digital | 01/01/2020 10:14:10 |
| 23455 | Call | 01/01/2020 10:30:10 |
| 55869 | Digital | 02/01/2020 09:00:01 |
| 55869 | Digital | 02/01/2020 14:00:00 |
| 55869 | Call | 02/01/2020 14:10:00 |

I want to generate a column that is populated with a unique id that groups together timestamps that are within 30 mins of one another for each prospect ID.

The output should look like this:

| Prospect_ID | Channel | Timestamp | Timestamp_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23455 | Digital | 01/01/2020 10:00:00 | abc1 |
| 23455 | Digital | 01/01/2020 10:14:10 | abc1 |
| 23455 | Call | 01/01/2020 10:30:10 | abc1 |
| 55869 | Digital | 01/01/2020 10:31:01 | abc2 |
| 55869 | Digital | 02/01/2020 14:00:00 | abc3 |
| 55869 | Call | 02/01/2020 14:10:00 | abc3 |

I am using Snowflake DB for this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag()` and a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_timestamp >= timestamp - interval '30 minute' then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by prospectid order by timestamp) as timestamp_id
from (select t.*,
             lag(timestamp) over (partition by prospectid order by timestamp) as prev_timestamp
      from t
     ) t;
```

If you want a unique number over all users, you can tweak the logic:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_timestamp >= timestamp - interval '30 minute' then 0 else 1 end) over (order by prospectid, timestamp) as timestamp_id
```

Comment: Thanks for that Gordon - how would I go about generating the unique timestamp id?

Comment: Sorry doesn't seem to work. It's setting every to 1 in the timestamp_id column.

Comment: I wonder whether I do another query to concat the prospect id with timestamp id?

Comment: Thanks - i tweaked it slightly and it now works :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Analytical function lag() and sum() with UDF.

```js
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION timestamp_UDF() 
RETURNS table(PROSPECT_ID INTEGER, CHANNEL VARCHAR2(10),
MY_TIMESTAMP timestamp, timestamp_id VARCHAR2(10))
AS  
$$
  select t.prospect_id,t.channel, t.my_timestamp,
  'abc '||sum(case when prev_timestamp >= my_timestamp - interval '30 minute' then 0 else 1 end) over (order by my_timestamp) as timestamp_id
   from (select t.*,
   lag(my_timestamp) over (order by my_timestamp) as prev_timestamp
    from table_name as t
   ) t
$$
;

select * from table(timestamp_UDF());
```

Comment: Please check how to format your answer and not submitting it like this. Check the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer